Getting gateway in bridge mode on a linux VM guest through a windows host
I have a SFP GPON ONU which I want to get it works in a OpenWRT VM on a Win11 host (VMWare Player).
Once the SFP module connects to the tree, it goes in bridge-mode.
I'm not sure this particular mode can go through the VM.
Also, I'm not sure the Intel 82599ES 10Gbs SFP+ can handle the job.
Today, the SFP module is plugged in a physical openWRT router with 1Gbs and working.
Thanks
